# Tomcat Setup to use TLS1.2 on outbound HTTPS connections

Tags: tomcat, tls1.2

I have a tomcat web application using Oracle JDK 1.7 which supports both https and http clients. Now my application needs to connect to an external application (through an API call) which supports only HTTPS / TLSv1.2. Specifically, when I try to make an API call, the third party server returns an error indicating that that I should use TLSv1.2.

When I use openjdk 1.7, the API call goes through, just fine.

1> How do I make the client connection use TLSv1.2 using Oracle JDK 1.7.

2> When I turn on TLSv1.2 does it mean that the server automatically uses TLSv1.2 for inbound connections as well ? If so, what would be implication for inbound browser clients connecting to my application ?